# How can use specific extjs store with same data in some panels?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs6

I'm developing a [MVVM Extjs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html) application. I have a [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) and I want to use this [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) in several [panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)'s. The data's [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store), in all [panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)s is same. I want to reload the [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) and call some function in some [panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)'s [viewController](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewController).

I have no idea. **How can I implement this feature**?

Comment: A panel can't have a store and isn't meant to hold data from a store. Can you provide us with more info, like a use case of what you're trying to accomplish? And why not use the same view is all is the same?

Comment: I'm using [OpneLayers 3](http://openlayers.org). I want to get data with store from server and then update my map, grid panel and template component, with this data. I need an event when data store changed to call some functions.

Comment: You can use the 'update' event of the store which is fired every time a record (model) has changed, and listen to it in the controller at your event domains (like a mediator). Or listen to the datachanged event when models are added or deleted.

Info about event domains:
http://existdissolve.com/2013/12/ext-js-custom-event-domains-and-complex-controller-event-selectors/
All events you can play with from there:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-add

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear for me whether you need to know how to connect your store to a panel, or you explicitly need to call something when the store updates.I will try to address both concerns.

### How things work:

The store is an object that connects to your sever and loads/updates that data. The store needs a model (a data model, not a view model) and a proxy (an object that tells it how to connect to your server). Something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'url_to_some_rest_api_function/',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'rows'
        },
        writer: {
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
});
```

And the model can be something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    /*Use mapping here if backend name is different*/
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'Name',
            mapping: 'FirstName'
        },
        {
            name: 'Email',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]

});
```

You can now build a panel to bind its data to this store and lets assume here a gird panel, like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.UsersGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    alias: 'widget.users-grid', 

    store: 'Users',
    autoLoad: true,

    selType: 'rowmodel',
    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            flex: 1,
            text: 'Name of the user'
        },
        {
            dataIndex: 'Email',
            flex: 1,
            text: 'Email'
        }
    ]
});
```

Notice the `autoLoad: true` part. This makes your grid load its data automatically when the view loads.
Now to manually reload this store in any view controller, using a button for example, you can use:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('users-grid')[0].getStore().reload();
```

This will also update your grid immediately.

### How to call your functions when store is changed

If you want to call some functions when the store is changed, add a handler to its datachanged event.

```
var myStore = Ext.getStore("Users");
myStore.on("datachanged", onDataChanged, this);

function onDataChanged(store){
    // code here
}
```